# Error while launching OfflineSigningActivity Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: android, flutter, docusign-sdk

I'm working on a Flutter plugin that wraps DocuSign's native SDKs for use in Flutter apps. I've set up the Method Channels for the most important features, and I'm currently working on offline signing. Here's a snippet of the Android implementation code:

```kotlin
class DocusignFlutterPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
  private lateinit var context: Context

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "docusign_flutter")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
  }

  // ...

  private fun signEnvelopeOfflineById(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    val envelopeId = call.argument<String>("envelopeId")!!

    DocuSign.getInstance().getSigningDelegate().signOffline(context, envelopeId, object : DSOfflineSigningListener{
      override fun onCancel(envelopeId: String) {
        // ...
      }

      override fun onError(exception: DSSigningException) {
        // ...
      }

      override fun onSuccess(envelopeId: String) {
        // ...
      }
    })
  }
}
```

However, I'm encountering an issue when calling the `signEnvelopeOfflineById` method. Specifically, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
"Error while launching OfflineSigningActivity
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
Is this really what you want?"
```

I think this error is related to the `context`, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm new to native Android development, and I mostly work with pure Flutter apps.

Any help or guidance would be great!